# Line break in table

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I want to go on writing in the first array but in a new line. The command `\\` is not working for this. Can anybody help me please?

My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\small
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Disability} \\ \cline{2-4}
  & Regulatory Framework & Coverage & Qualifying Conditions \\ \hline
  United States & \textbf{Social Security Act 1935} & xx &  xx \\ \hline
  Germany & xx & xx & xx \\ \hline
  France & xx & xx & xx \\ \hline
  United Kingdom & xx & xx & xx \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT** An image to make it clearer how the table should look like.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, please make sure that you enter your code correctly. To mark text as code, use four (4) spaces at every line to make sure StackExchange appropriately shows it as code (with a little gray box). Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand your question -- can you make a sketch of how the table should look like?

Comment: @ChristianH. http://abload.de/image.php?img=testtkiktg.jpg

Comment: If I understand this table correctly, it is basically the 'US' row? Why do you not just add an empty table row? I can post the solution if this the case...

Comment: Is it then possible to do non-automaticly line-break? That would be fine, if you could post the solution.

Answer (score 3):

[image: table with a multirow column]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\small
\begin{tabular}{lp{4cm}p{1.2cm}p{3.5cm}}
\toprule
  \multirow{2}{*} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Disability} \\ \cmidrule(r){2-4}
  & Regulatory Framework & Coverage & Qualifying Conditions \\ \midrule
  United States & \raggedright
Social Security Act 1935 and related bills passed over a period of many     years by various Congresspersons despite the blatant attempts to filibuster by     making long and pointless sentences that seem to run on forever just to     demonstrate verbosity of the political classes
& xx &  xx \\ 
  Germany & xx & xx & xx \\ 
  France & xx & xx & xx \\ 
  United Kingdom & xx & xx & xx \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps, you should an image how your table looks like?

Comment: making that column into one based on paragraphs is the right way to go, but it would look nicer ragged right.